# Niche MapInfo Question : Digitising options

Tags: mapinfo, digitizing

I've recently started using mapinfo to digitise on a daily basis, I am usually georefencing old deeds (on top of OS Mastermap) and then digitising them.

The problem is when drawing the polygon the default colour of that line is grey, it would be much better if that line was a bright colour as it can be easy to lose ones place when digitising from black and white deeds.

So my question is, is there an option to change the colour of the lines of polygon before it's finished.

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not. The color and width of the digitizing line can't be changed.
You can however change the cursor.

If you hit the x key on the keyboard while having the map window as the active window, you can switch between three cursor sizes.

You can also turn a full screen cursor on and off with the c key on the keyboard. This turns a cursor similar to the one you'll find in AutoCAD on and off.

Both these features have been in MapInfo Pro since v11.0 or earlier.